# AADSTS70002, AADSTS50053 errors connecting to Office 365 Sharepoint using Python

Tags: python, python-requests, office365, sharepoint-online

I have a Python program that sometimes connects to SharePoint on Office 365 and sometimes fails. I am currently seeing the following symptoms.

Here is the part of the code that is failing with my print statements to show the input and output:

```
    sts_url = 'https://' + options['sts']['host'] + options['sts']['path']
    print(sts_url)
    print(request_body)
    response = requests.post(sts_url, data=request_body,
                             headers={'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'})
    print(response.content)
```

Here is the standard output except with my user id, password,and SharePoint URL replaced with fake values for security:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/extSTS.srf
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
  <s:Header>
    <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust/RST/Issue</a:Action>
    <a:ReplyTo>
      <a:Address>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</a:Address>
    </a:ReplyTo>
    <a:To s:mustUnderstand="1">https://login.microsoftonline.com/extSTS.srf</a:To>
    <o:Security s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
      <o:UsernameToken>
        <o:Username>My.User@mydomain.com</o:Username>
        <o:Password>Mypassword</o:Password>
      </o:UsernameToken>
    </o:Security>
  </s:Header>
  <s:Body>
    <t:RequestSecurityToken xmlns:t="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust">
      <wsp:AppliesTo xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy">
        <a:EndpointReference>
          <a:Address>https://mydomain.sharepoint.com/sites/MyTeams/Mypath/</a:Address>
        </a:EndpointReference>
      </wsp:AppliesTo>
      <wsp:PolicyReference xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" URI="MBI"></wsp:PolicyReference>
      <t:KeyType>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/NoProofKey</t:KeyType>
      <t:RequestType>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust/Issue</t:RequestType>
      <t:TokenType>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:assertion</t:TokenType>
    </t:RequestSecurityToken>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>

b'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><S:Envelope xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" 
xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" 
xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" 
xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" 
xmlns:wst="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust" 
xmlns:S="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"><S:Header><psf:pp 
xmlns:psf="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Passport/SoapServices/SOAPFault">
<psf:serverVersion>1</psf:serverVersion><psf:authstate>0x80048800</psf:authstate>
<psf:reqstatus>0x80048823</psf:reqstatus><psf:serverInfo ServerTime="2018-07-24T21:37:51.884595Z">
PROD-WST-011.ProdSlices rid:82319104-8158-4804-9b33-966102135800</psf:serverInfo></psf:pp>
</S:Header><S:Body xmlns:S="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"><S:Fault><S:Code>
<S:Value>S:Sender</S:Value><S:Subcode><S:Value>wst:FailedAuthentication</S:Value></S:Subcode>
</S:Code><S:Reason><S:Text xml:lang="en-US">Authentication Failure</S:Text></S:Reason><S:Detail>
<psf:error xmlns:psf="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Passport/SoapServices/SOAPFault">
<psf:value>0x80048823</psf:value><psf:internalerror><psf:code>0x80048823</psf:code>
<psf:text>AADSTS70002: Error validating credentials. AADSTS50053: You\'ve tried to sign in too many
times with an incorrect user ID or password.</psf:text></psf:internalerror></psf:error></S:Detail>
</S:Fault></S:Body></S:Envelope>'
```

Here is standard error output:

```
An error occurred while retrieving token: AADSTS70002: Error validating credentials. AADSTS50053: You've tried to sign in too many times with an incorrect user ID or password.
An error occurred while retrieving auth cookies
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testsimplified.py", line 24, in <module>
    context.request_form_digest()
  File "C:\todoitems\pysharepointerrers\office365\sharepoint\client_context.py", line 33, in request_form_digest
    self.authenticate_request(request)
  File "C:\todoitems\pysharepointerrers\office365\runtime\client_runtime_context.py", line 16, in authenticate_request
    self.__auth_context.authenticate_request(request)
  File "C:\todoitems\pysharepointerrers\office365\runtime\auth\authentication_context.py", line 27, in authenticate_request
    request_options.set_header('Cookie', self.provider.get_authentication_cookie())
  File "C:\todoitems\pysharepointerrers\office365\runtime\auth\saml_token_provider.py", line 69, in get_authentication_cookie
    return 'FedAuth=' + self.FedAuth + '; rtFa=' + self.rtFa
TypeError: must be str, not NoneType
```

This is all based on some code I hacked together from an earlier SO post. Here is my code for uploading a file to SharePoint on Office 365.

https://github.com/bobbydurrett/miscpython/blob/master/uploadfile.py

Sometimes it works great. Other times I get errors. I don't get the AADSTS50053 error at first. At first I get the wrong password error. But every time it runs it is with the correct user id and password.

Any ideas? I also submitted an issue about this on GitHub:

https://github.com/vgrem/Office365-REST-Python-Client/issues/80

For this SO question I found the requests post where the error was occurring and posted the before and after values.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Bobby